Why is Authentication null in my controller when using @WithMockUser in the test?
Question:
I have the following code in my controller:
@MessageMapping(MESSAGE_MAPPING)
public void sendVote(final RequestVoteDto vote, final Authentication authentication) {
    final UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    voteService.createVote(vote, userDetails.getUsername());
}

And this is the test I’m using:
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "userTest")
@DisplayName("Send vote should be accessible for authorized user")
void testSendVote_shouldBeAccessibleForAuthorizedUser() throws Exception {
    // test code here
}

However, the Authentication object in the controller is always null, so it seems like @WithMockUser(username = "userTest") is not working as expected.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?
I created a custom @WithCustomAuthenticationPrincipal annotation:
public class WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithCustomAuthenticationPrincipal> {

    @Override
    public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(final WithCustomAuthenticationPrincipal customUser) {
        final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

        final UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(
                new User()
                        .setEmail(customUser.username())
                        .setPassword(customUser.password())
                        .setSecurityRole(customUser.role())
        );

        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        return context;
    }
}

I also tested it with the following code:
@Test
@WithCustomAuthenticationPrincipal(username = "user@example.com", password = "password", role = SecurityRole.ROLE_ADMIN)
void testAuthenticationIsNotNull() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        assertNotNull(authentication);
        assertEquals("user@example.com", ((UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }

The test passed, but when I applied my annotation to a "main" test, nothing changed — the Authentication is still null in the Controller.
